# Is semver now a standard?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

Is there any reason a new public project being started, if given the choice (e.g., not constrained by their company), would use something other than [Semver](http://semver.org/)? Are there competing methodologies, i.e., Semver has not been widely accepted yet?

This question arises because a very well known package that I use updated from 3.2 to 3.3. I blindly updated, thinking this could only add new APIs, not break old APIs. And to my surprise, 3.3 deleted some deprecated APIs. Checking their versioning, it did not state what "system" they use.

So, should we assume Semver is the default for [most/all] Github projects?

Edit: [semver.org](http://semver.org)

Edit2: I think this debate greatly depends on whether the software is a *library* or an *end application* (the user is sitting in front of it interacting with it). My original intention was to discuss the former. That is, if the code can be a dependency in other code. Non-semver libraries make it very hard to know whether it is safe to download a newer version of the library and depend on it. In contrast, I don't care what something like the version Firefox is because you aren't using it as a library, you're using it as an end application.

Comment: For a random project found on Github, I wouldn't assume anything.

Comment: By "Semver", I assume you mean "Semantic Versioning?"  If it's a standard, it's a defacto one; I don't know of any governing body that enforces such a standard, nor is there any way to force people to write their code in a way that does not introduce breaking changes within major versions.

Comment: **Worth noting:** Deprecated API's are so deprecated precisely because they're not guaranteed to survive in future versions of the software.  The developer of the software in question apparently decided that they'd provided adequate warning by deprecating the API that was eventually removed, though I do agree that he should have changed the major version before removing the deprecated API.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In fact, I, as a user, would even take deprecation as a *promise* to not burden me with obsolete code. I get frequently annoyed, for example, that the Java 8 JRE still contains methods and classes that have been marked as deprecated since Java 1.2, I believe. Why do I have to download that code? Why do I have to have such old, unused and thus probably less well-maintained and less rigorously security-reviewed code on my machine?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would have been totally OK with removing all deprecated APIs in 4.0.

Comment: Actually of the various libraries that I use a lot where I'm aware of how they do versioning (that's 4 or 5 or so) there aren't any that use "semver". In practice you simply must always check the release notes, version numbers are essentially meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

[Semantic versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Degree_of_compatibility) is not, AFAIK, an *official* standard (by some organization like ISO). But they are so many of them that we cannot be sure (and I certainly do not know most of ISO standards).

And some software do not use it. For example, [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) is releasing versions which are named after chemical element (e.g. Beryllium; But Magnesium was released in January 2016).

Some software have changed their versioning scheme during their lifetime. A notable example includes [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (and probably also the Linux kernel): GCC used to number 4.1, 4.2, .... for significant version changes (with patchlevels like 4.1.2 or 4.1.3 for small bug fixes), but now they are using version numbers like 5 or 6 (with 5.3 being a patchlevel).

Some software libraries don't always have any version number, e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (an HTTP server library for C & C++, on [github](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion); but it has some [git-version-gen](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/blob/master/git-version-gen) script).

<sup>(maybe I am wrong, and `libonion` is perhaps getting versioning info & API)</sup>

Linux linker provides symbol versioning. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015367/how-to-achieve-symbol-versioning).

Some C-callable libraries provide preprocessor symbols guiding the implemented API. GCCJIT [uses](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/topics/compatibility.html) "symbol tags" like `LIBGCCJIT_ABI_2`. See also [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) & [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) on Linux.

The [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Version-Information.html) library (in GTK) provides an interesting version information API which could be inspirational.

GCC & Clang have the `__attribute__((deprecated))`  [function attribute](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Version-Information.html) to mark functions which are deprecated. C++14 [specifies](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) the `[[deprecated]]` attribute. If you publish a library with a significant user community, you probably would make some functions as deprecated in some release, and remove them entirely only in some future release. Notice that in the C standard, the infamous [gets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#gets) function was removed many years after have been announced as deprecated.

Comment: and don't forget Google Chome that introduced the nonsense versioning system of a single ever-increasing number.

Comment: Nah. [GNU `less`](https://gnu.org/software/less/) did that long before Google even existed. The current version is 481.

Comment: Just another random example: The [Rubinius](http://rubinius.com/) project's [versioning scheme](http://rubinius.com/2015/09/22/major-minor-maximize-delivering-features-minimize-trouble/), its [release process](http://rubinius.com/2015/09/23/distributed-coding-distributed-releases/), and a [comment](http://rubinius.com/2016/01/07/rubinius-3-0-the-third-epoch/) on the former two (quote: "The Rubinius versioning scheme is emphatically *not* SemVer."). Another example: [Rakudo](http://rakudo.org/)'s current release is Rakudo* (Rakudo Star) 2016.01, which includes Rakudo 2016.01.1 which …

Comment: … implements Perl v6.c.

Comment: RE libonion, I don't understand how that works. How do you manage dependencies in a software project if your dependencies can just change under you? Do you freeze "some versionless copy that you know works"..?

Comment: @Tommy: I'm mostly a user of libonion (with some few *minor* contributions to it). I feel the lack of version info -thru some API- as some deficiency. So far, onion did not evolve incompatibly, and it probably has "few" users (and those who do use it are compiling it). But I am not sure to understand your question...

Comment: And of course there is TeX, which has a version number that converges to pi (the most recent version is 3.14159265).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I edited my question. Tex is mostly used as a set of binaries, not libraries, so this cute nonsense is fine.